# How do you calculate the time complexity of an algorithm that rewrites its code?

Tags: time-complexity, complexity-theory

Has anyone seen any research on this? Are there any frameworks or approaches to calculating the complexity of a non-fixed algorithm?

Thanks,
Louise

Comment: It's still deterministic, so i don't see anything different from classic analysis here.

Comment: As far as I know, one usually proceeds by i) looking at the code, ii) unrolling it into sections which have a particular complexity, iii) combining these into an equation which shows the overall time in function of problem size.

This is because complexity analysis is so difficult that there isn't an algorithm for it, so we have to do it "by eye."

Do you agree?